# EGOPhotoViewer, take urls from an NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray, photo

I'm parsing an xml file (that contains urls of images), taking the urls from the tag  and adding it on an NSMutableArray!

I'm using EGOPhotoViewer, and all photos-url need this code:

```
            EGOPhoto *photo1 = [[EGOPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://a3.twimg.com/profile_images/66601193/cactus.jpg"] name:@" laksd;lkas;dlkaslkd ;a"];
```

In my NSMutableArray, repeat, i have only the urls.

How can i do?
Thanks!

(of course, the problem is that i don't know how many pictures i have, so i don't know how many variable EGOPhoto i need to create!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a for loop:

```
for (NSString *imgURL in aMutableArrayInstance) {
    EGOPhoto *photo1 = [[EGOPhoto alloc] initWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL] name:@"WhateverNameYouWant"];
    // Do whatever awesome stuff you need to do with photo1
    [photo1 release];
}
```